# Problem Configuring Swagger openAPI 3.0 Authentication with firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, openapi, swagger-3.0

I am using the swagger openAPI for retrieving data of firestore. I wanted to apply security from swagger not from firestore and when i do this and perform GET request UI displays the data stored on firestore and not display the unauthenticated message.